# How to specify the methods and routes while creating REST API for a resource with loopback.io?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

It appears that by default all methods (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE and HEAD) are enabled when a REST API is created for a resource. Is it possible to generate REST APIs only for a subset of these methods (for ex. only GET) ?

Could you please point me to the file where all the routes and methods are registered to the handlers so that I can try commenting out the ones I don't need ?

Regards,
Subramanian

Answer (score 0):

You can hide Endpoints, look at the section "Hiding methods and REST endpoints":

[Exposing models over REST](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Exposing+models+over+REST)